# AngularJs Custom Directive scope data overwritten

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope, angularjs-compile

I have displayed the products based on branch and billing account. In the product template, i have a "+" button, if we click on the button, then i'm displaying the particular product id below that product template.

Now the problem is, when i click the "+" button of "Product 1" , then it display product id as "300152". its fine. After that If i click the "+" button next to "Product 2", its displaying product id as "300153" below both "Product 1" and "Product 2". This is the issue. Please check the following fiddle. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

[JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/fokv7Lhh/31/)

```
TabsApp.directive('productTemplate', ['$compile', 
                                                 function($compile){
     return {
        restrict: "E",
        scope: {
      branchdata : '='
        },
    //templateUrl : templateSupportTabV3, 
  template: ' <li ng-repeat= "(prod_index, product) in branchdata.moduleLevel3List   "><span class="normal-negrita">{{product.name}} (ID.{{product.id}})</span><a class = "cursor" ng-click="load_productInfo_branch(  branch_index + 1 ,  prod_index + 1 ,  product.id  , branchdata.id );"><span id="more_product_body_{{branchdata.id}}_{{ product.id }}" class="normal" style="font-size:10px;"> &nbsp;+&nbsp;</span> </a><div id="product_body_{{branchdata.id}}_{{product.id}}" class="product_panel_container"></div></li> ',
        link: function (scope, elem, attrs) {

            scope.load_productInfo_branch = function(baIndex, productIndex, productId,branchId){ 
                 debugger;

                  scope.prdouctType = productId; 
                  var resp = "<p >ID : {{prdouctType}} </P>";
                  var divId = document.getElementById("product_body_" + branchId+"_"+productId);

                  divId.innerHTML=resp;
                  $compile(divId)(scope);


            };
 }
    };
}]);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the working JS Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/fokv7Lhh/38/

You can use one way binding

```
var resp = "<p >ID : {{::prdouctType}} </p>";
```

Do you really need to apply to the scope? Another way to show the value is something like this:

```
var resp = "<p >ID : " + productId + "</p>";
```

Answer (score 2):

You are using two-way binding while adding new DOM child; and there is one "prdouctType" in the scope. So,

```
var resp = "<p >ID : {{prdouctType}} </P>";
```

should be something like

```
var resp = "<p >ID : " + scope.prdouctType + "</P>";
```

Comment: Its not possible. For testing, i used dummy content for  var resp . But Actually, it will hold a jsp file content., var resp = code_to_readfile('productdetails.jsp');

Comment: Cloning the produced html (changing `divId.innerHTML=resp;` to `divId.innerHTML=angular.copy(resp);`) may help you.

Comment: You are still using two-way binding in resp. Set resp according to my answer. By the way, what is in "productdetails.jsp"?

Comment: in productdetails.jsp, we have all details of product like id, subproducts, etc, This file have more then 100 lines of code. so its not good to keep it in js file.

Comment: I suggest you to use html templates for both directive template and "productdetail.jsp" replacement. Besides, it is not good practice to set innerHtml while using AngularJS; instead one should use html templates.

Comment: Thanks @kursad. I implemented one way binding, then its working.

Answer (score 0):

Add in bindToController:

```
bindToController: true,
scope: {
  branchData: '='
}
```

That should stop it happening.

Answer (score 0):

Hello If you want to keep the `{{prdouctType}}` the same. You can try something like this.

You can hide the previous div and open the new one.

```js
var TabsApp = angular.module('TabsApp', []);

TabsApp.controller('IndexCtrl', function ($scope) {
 $scope.tabdata =[{"id":49844,"name":"Billing account 1","entityType":"BA","moduleLevel2List":[{"id":2239,"name":"branch 1","entityType":"BRANCH","moduleLevel3List":[{"id":300152,"name":"PRoduct 1","entityType":"PRODUCT"},{"id":300153,"name":"PRoduct 2","entityType":"PRODUCT"},{"id":300154,"name":"PRoduct 3","entityType":"PRODUCT"}]}]},{"id":49845,"name":"Billing account 2","entityType":"BA","moduleLevel2List":[{"id":2240,"name":"branch 2","entityType":"BRANCH","moduleLevel3List":[{"id":300127,"name":"PRoduct 4","entityType":"PRODUCT"}]}]}];
});

TabsApp.directive('supportTabV3Directive', ['$compile', 
                                                 function($compile){
  return {
  restrict: "E",
  scope: {
   tabdata : '='
  },
 //templateUrl : templateSupportTabV3, 
  template: '<li name="billing_{{ ba_index + 1}}"  ng-repeat = "(ba_index, ba) in tabdata   "><span class="bold">{{ba.name}} (ID. {{ba.id}})</span><ul><li ng-repeat = "(branch_index, branch) in ba.moduleLevel2List   "><span class="normal">Nombre: {{branch.name}}</span><ul><product-template branchdata="branch" ></product-template></ul></li>',
  link: function (scope, elem, attrs) {
   
   
 }
 };
}]);



TabsApp.directive('productTemplate', ['$compile', 
                                                 function($compile){
  return {
  restrict: "E",
  scope: {
      branchdata : '='
  },
 //templateUrl : templateSupportTabV3, 
  template: ' <li ng-repeat= "(prod_index, product) in branchdata.moduleLevel3List   "><span class="normal-negrita">{{product.name}} (ID.{{product.id}})</span><a class = "cursor" ng-click="load_productInfo_branch(  branch_index + 1 ,  prod_index + 1 ,  product.id  , branchdata.id );"><span>{{productType}} </span> <span id="more_product_body_{{branchdata.id}}_{{ product.id }}" class="normal" style="font-size:10px;"> &nbsp;+&nbsp;</span> </a><div id="product_body_{{branchdata.id}}_{{product.id}}" class="product_panel_container"></div></li>',
  link: function (scope, elem, attrs) {
   
   scope.load_productInfo_branch = function(baIndex, productIndex, productId,branchId){ 
         
         scope.prdouctType = productId; 
            if(document.querySelector('#test'))
            {
            document.querySelector('#test').remove()
            }
            
         var resp = "<p id='test'>ID : {{prdouctType}} </P>";
         var divId = document.getElementById("product_body_" + branchId+"_"+productId);
            console.log(divId);
         divId.innerHTML=resp;
         $compile(divId)(scope);
         
            
   };
 }
 };
}]);
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/underscore.js/1.6.0/underscore-min.js
"></script>
<body>

<div ng-app = "TabsApp">
 <div ng-controller="IndexCtrl">
  
  <support-tab-v3-directive tabdata="tabdata"></support-tab-v3-directive>
    </div>
</div>



</body>
</html>
```

**You can run the above snippet**

(OR)

[**HEre is a DEMO for it**](https://plnkr.co/edit/LVe6Y6GJQdsQCSeGeakW?p=preview)

Comment: @Ananth, please check my answer.

Comment: As per my requirement, i should not remove that product type details until user click on the "-" symbol. so it wont work for that scenario.